# Qt application cannot find shared library at runtime

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt Creator to build a GUI application, which depends on some extra libs. It works quite well when I run the application from Qt Creator. But while I try to start the application by double-clicking or from console, I found it failed to find those libs. 
In my `.pro` file, I configured the lib directory as follows:

```
MYDLLDIR = $$OUT_PWD/libs
INCLUDEPATH += $$MYDLLDIR
win32:LIBS += $$quote($$MYDLL/test.dll)
unix:LIBS += $$quote(-L$$MYDLLDIR) -ltest
```

My `test.so` and `test.so.1` and all others are under libs directory in my output folder. How can I make it to find those libs also during runtime? 
Thank you.

**Extra Note:** I'm running under Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You need to deploy a lot of libs for your application. Try this documentation to get an overview: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html

Comment: Btw, I'm running under Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe it should be `unix:LIBS` and not `unix:LIBs`?

Comment: Sorry, that's my typo while posting here. I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible solutions.

You can install your shared library to standard locations like `/usr/lib`, `/lib` or `/usr/lib64` etc.

Or before running your application from console,
you can set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to include 
the directory which contains your shared library.

See this [link](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it by coping those files under `/usr/lib`.